# How can I return an int value from a SQLite query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, linqpad, sqlite-net

I've got this SQLite method:

```
internal static bool DataContainsAnyLocationInfo()
{
    int latCount = 0;
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM PhotraxBaseData WHERE latitude > 0.0";
        latCount = db.Query<PhotraxBaseData>(sql);
    }
    return (latCount > 0);
}
```

...that won't compile due to: "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'*"

I just want an int back, such as 0 or 1 or 42, not an entire List.

I do have sqlite-net installed, if there's a way to do it with that that would be easier, not excluding a LINQy way, if that'll work.

### UPDATE

Maybe I'd be better off doing it this way instead:

```
internal static bool DataContainsAnyLocationInfo(List<PhotraxBaseData> _pbd)
{
    bool locInfoFound = false;
    foreach (PhotraxBaseData pbd in _pbd)
    {
        if (pbd.latitude > 0.0)
        {
            locInfoFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return locInfoFound;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

John Woo's code compiles, but my SQL must be bad, because, although I have many records in PhotraxBaseData where latitude is greater than 0, the function returns false.

And when I run either of these queries directly in LINQPad4:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM PhotraxBaseData WHERE latitude > 0.0
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM PhotraxBaseData WHERE (latitude > 0.0)
```

I get:

```
) or end of expression expected
; expected
```

**Note:** *latitude* is a double.

### UPDATE 3

So now I've got two ways that work (my non-database-touching code above, and John Woo's "ExecuteScalar" code), but I don't know which one is preferable. They are both faster than a famished hummingbird zipping toward newly-discovered nectar.

Comment: are you using `.Query<T>` from `Dapper`?

Comment: Nope; never heard of him.

Comment: Please see Update 2.

Comment: if you are querying for an `int`why have you given the Query the type argument of `PhotraxBaseData`, should it not just be  `db.Query<int>(sql).Single();`

Comment: from their [documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net), you can use this code `latCount = db.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql);` since it will return a row other than a list. I don't know why you are getting that error but it will run on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bc8e3/2).

Comment: Yep - that works, all right. Make it an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from their [documentation](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net), you can use this code:

```
latCount = db.ExecuteScalar<int>(sql);
```

since it will return a row other than a list. I don't know why you are getting that error but your query will run on SQLFiddle.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bc8e3/2)